# Thunderbird :: Stuck at Google sign-in

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

After updating my personal Gmail account password, I am unable to reconnect my Thunderbird to my Gmail account. I get to the Google login page, but when I click 'Next' nothing happens.

I have uninstalled, purged and ran it after a fresh install from a download through the shell, but I get the same issue. Not sure if this is a bug or something else. I ran it from command line; turned off the firewall; and checked `dmesg`, but none yielded any useful information.

Update: I figured that since I was able to set up Thunderbird once on Ubuntu 16.1, then a fresh install--without running `apt-get update` and `upgrade`--should do it. But to no avail.

I also tried setting up a new Gmail account, again no avail. This is frustrating. I really like using Thunderbird to manage my Gmail.

Update2: I have another computer with Linux Mint, it has the exact same issue. Is this something wrong with Gmail? Does it have to do with permissions?

Here's the screen where I get stuck:

[image: Google sign in for Thunderbird]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does "more options" do anything?

Comment: @George It is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Organic Marble 
The 'more options' button's background animates, but does nothing. If I try other buttons or links, they either do nothing or crash Thunderbird. I am running it from command, yet even when it crashes, the command line doesn't present any error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I progress beyond entering my username when configuring Thunderbird to use Gmail?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910614/why-cant-i-progress-beyond-entering-my-username-when-configuring-thunderbird-to). OP's self-answer just refers to an [answer posted to this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/910630).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had asked the same question today and got this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/a/910630/621017

It worked for me, but I had to reboot after uninstalling and only then reinstalled TB.

Comment: what versions work or don't?  (assuming it's a version number thing.)

Answer (score 1):

Alternate Workaround:

If anyone needs a **workaround** for any reason as I did, here is one option to consider to get your gmail working in Thunderbird without the patch or beta release.

**First** in your gmail account you will need to have “Allow less secure apps” turned on.  You can always turn this back off when you have OAuth working again. 
[Google tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxsm2.png)

**Next**, In Thunderbird > account settings > server settings >
        Change the Authentication method from “OAuth” to “Normal Password”.
[Auth setting screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pf1Y7.png)

**Last** change the SMTP server settings to normal as well (to be able to send out email).

This got me back into my email when I can’t get the latest patch for **Thunderbird** easily.

Comment: This did the trick (after allowing it in Google): "Change the Authentication method from “OAuth” to “Normal Password".  NOTE: If you're adding a new Gmail account, you have to click "Manual Config" to be able to access this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem just now. I uninstalled the plugin and reinstalled it, and then the sign-in screen worked normally.

Comment: which plugin?  how did you uninstall it?

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/provider-for-google-calendar/ I only use google calendar in thunderbird, not gmail.

Answer (score -3):

You can use VPN to change your IP address to a country (e.g. Hongkong) where the default login page is still the old one.

Comment: Either Google updated the login page or my VPN is lying about routing me through Hong Kong. Either way, this didn't work for me sadly.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: @UnqtiousDude Have you cleared your cookies

Comment: @Taptic How do you clear the cookies in Thunderbird? Delete the .thunderbird folder?

Comment: Preferences, Privacy, Show Cookies, select the cookie for Google, Remove Selected

Comment: not related to where logging from.  not bad general troubleshooting, points for being thorough, but not the error/bug/problem.