# Why can't I progress beyond entering my username when configuring Thunderbird to use Gmail?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

I've always used my Gmail accounts with Thunderbird. Until two days ago I was using them and then I decided to install Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 - which I had previously used and worked fine with Gmail+Thunderbird -, now I can't get through the Google sign in to configure my imap gmail account.

I enter the appropriate info and when I hit done it goes to that usual google page where you have to enter your username and then hit next to enter the password. That's when it gets stuck: I hit next and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/910327/18612) looks related, although there does not appear to be a good answer there yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to install the beta version of Thunderbird. Please follow these steps.

1. Open a terminal window;
2. Uninstall current version of thunderbird by entering:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove thunderbird
   ```
3. Add "thunderbird-next" ppa (contains releases of Thunderbird from the beta channel) by entering:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
   ```
4. Download the package lists from the repositories and update them by entering:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install the new version of Thunderbird by entering:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install thunderbird
   ```
6. After installation ends close the terminal window. Now you should have the 1:54.0 version of the software. You can check this opening thunderbird, and clicking "Help" > "about thunderbird" from the menu. A new window appears informing the version.
7. Now you can configure the Google account normally.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much!
(Actually, I had to reboot for it to work. Just reinstalling TB wasn't enough, even doing apt update)

Answer (score 2):

That was a bug in Thunderbird 52.0.1, concerning improvement on Google sign-in process on Apr 20, 2017.

see: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

And it was fixed in Thunderbird 52.1.0 released today, Apr 30, 2017.

refer to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1359297

Answer (score 2):

Alternate Workaround:

If anyone needs a **workaround** for any reason as I did, here is one option to consider to get your gmail working in Thunderbird without the patch or beta release.

**First** in your gmail account you will need to have “Allow less secure apps” turned on.  You can always turn this back off when you have OAuth working again.  [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) is the link to the setting. 
[Google tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxsm2.png)

**Next**, In Thunderbird > account settings > server settings >
        Change the Authentication method from “OAuth” to “Normal Password”.

**Last** change the SMTP server settings to normal as well (to be able to send out email).

This got me back into my email when I can’t get the latest patch for **Thunderbird** easily.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this (or something similar) in Thunderbird 78.8.1 on Ubuntu 20.4.2 after changing a Gmail password - though I'm assuming that "nothing happens" is shorthand for "it doesn't do what I want" : when I clicked "Next" it reverted to the e-mail entry screen but without the autocompleted address, so something happened, but it didn't get me any further.

Steve's workaround ("normal password") gets around things nicely, but I was able to get where I wanted without allowing "less secure" access or uninstalling / reinstalling anything.

It looks like OAuth2 tokens are considered as cookies by Thunderbird, so allowing cookies temporarily in Preferences / Privacy and Security / Web content, deleting both (POP/IMAP and SMTP) stored passwords for that account in Preferences / Privacy and Security / Saved Passwords, coming out of Thunderbird and going back in again will give the same Google prompt with autocompleted e-mail address, but now clicking "Next" prompts for the new password and connects to Gmail, which seems to overwrite the OAuth token.

Cookies can then be disabled again.

[This won't help if you initially had cookies enabled, but I haven't seen the same problem with those settings.]