# Thunderbird :: Stuck at Google sign-in (xenial)

Tags: email, thunderbird, google, gmail, email-client

Can't get past this thunderbird dialog:

[image]

even though less secure apps are enabled:

[image]

Thunderbird is [explicitly](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) allowed:

```
Mozilla Thunderbird Email
Has access to Gmail
Homepage: 
https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird
Has access to:
Gmail
Read, send, delete and manage your email
Access given on:
26 July 2016
```

The version is 38.6.0 so cannot see why a [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/a/910630/45156) would be necessary, particularly when the version installed is greater than that suggested.  Potentially, re-installing a plug-in would [fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/913602/45156) this.

System:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
thufir@doge:~$
```

The "more options" button's background animates, but does nothing.

Probably switching from `OAuth` to "regular password", per one of the other answers in linked questions, would work.

Answer (score 0):

higher version number for thunderbird:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ thunderbird -v
 Thunderbird 52.4.0
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"
thufir@dur:~$
```

worked on clean install without configuring or reconfiguring anything on google or gmail.  Some sort of bug with older thunderbird versions most likely.

[image: enter credentials]