# Authentication failure while connecting to server imap.gmail.com

Tags: email, thunderbird, google, gmail, email-client

Is there some [persistent](https://askubuntu.com/q/967013/45156) problem with how Thunderbird interacts with Gmail?  I've authorized Thunderbird numerous times but am caught in a [loop](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.support.thunderbird/54YltTGGjSM/y8zcvtd7GwAJ).

I've logged into the browser numerous times, check and re-checked the password.  On another account, on the same pc, Thunderbird connects to this Gmail account fine.  So, it's certainly not a question of configuring the account to allow Thunderbird access.

Again, on the same pc, a different account accesses this Gmail account through Thunderbird without any problems.

Why does Thunderbird keep insisting that there's a password problem?  I'm just not *that* bad at typing in passwords...

> Unable to login at server. Probably wrong configuration, username or
>   password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per:  https://superuser.com/a/1499160/55747

---

Solution suggested in [this](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/4528103?hl=en) thread solved my problem.

It seems, that gmail fails authentication when it detects useragent of inbuilt Thunderbird browser.

The solution is to set `"general.useragent.compatMode.firefox"` property to `true`. This is done with config editor (Options > Advanced > General > Config Editor...).

Comment: Thanks! This solved the `Authentication failure` error with Yahoo IMAP too.